# Elasticsearch query that use 'terms' and 'missing' at same time

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I am trying to use this query to get all documents with a closed or pending status or with no status at all.but this query always return nothing.

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            "terms": {
                "status": ["closed","pending"]
            },
            "missing":{
                "field":"status"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Individually the queries are working.If I use:
    `"query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                "terms": {
                    "status": ["closed","pending"]
                }
            ]
        }
    }`

then it returns 2 documents.

And if I use

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [               
            "missing":{
                "field":"status"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

it returns 3.

These results are correct for each query.I just want to combine the 2 queries and get the result 5.What is wrong with the first query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ES 5.0 query and it should work on version 2.0

```
POST es1/example/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "status": [
              "closed",
              "pending"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "status"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```